# What do you call the process of processing data before triggering an event?

Tags: single-word-requests, programming

If I have a process below in an Event-Oriented System, Pub-Sub System, or etc:

`Receive Input -> Process Data -> Decide if to Trigger Event -> Trigger Event`

what word or process can I call this part of the process:

`Process Data -> Decide if to Trigger Event`

Comment: AssessTriggerConditions

Comment: **handleInput()** or **processInput()**

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the question seems to me to be not about English language and usage but about English-like computer-language nomenclature (as the comments suggesting as answers "AssessTriggerConditions," "handleinput()," and "processinput()" seem to confirm).

Answer (score 2):

It's called ***[validation](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/validate)***

> Check or prove the validity or accuracy of

[ODO]

You populate the input parameters and ***validate*** them so as to check if they match the pre-conditions set by you according to your business/context. 
If (and only if) *validation* passes for all parameters, you will trigger the next event or invoke subsequent methods.

Comment: Wouldn't it be more accurate to say that you check, assess, or evaluate the validity of the input? Validation is normally more the declaration of something being valid, than the actual checking of validity.

Comment: Since OP hasn't specified what *kind* of "event" might be triggered, we've no idea whether triggering that event is meaningfully related to any "validation" process. It may be that for all practical purposes it's not even *possible* for the input data to be "invalid", and/or that OP's "service routine" doesn't even contain any code checking for "validity" as such.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the word you are looking for is [evaluate](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/evaluate).

> 2. to judge or determine the significance, worth, or quality of...

Or you could use assess, a synonym of evaluate. They both mean to judge something, to determine how valuable or how important it is. Similar to how your process is deciding wether or not the information relates to the event in question.